# Get Brightcove Videos from repeating field in WordPress via ACF

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, brightcove

I have a repeating field in a WordPress site via ACF repeating fields:

```
      <?php
      if( have_rows('recent_episodes') ):
        $i = 1;
          while ( have_rows('recent_episodes') ) : the_row();

        $image = get_sub_field('video_image');
      ?>

      <!--API CODE HERE-->

        <li class="recent-episode-<?php the_sub_field('brightcove_video_id'); ?> col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">
            <div class="flex-caption">
              <h6 class="date"><?php the_sub_field('air_date') ?></h6>
              <h5 class="title"></h5>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
      <?php
      $i++;
      endwhile; else :
      endif;
      ?>
```

The brightcove_video_id field is a video ID for a video in Brightcove. Ideally, I would like to pull in the corresponding title for each video in the repeating field. When I put the API code in the repeating area though, it just outputs the last item each time. Here is what I have for the API code:

```
          var token = "HIDDEN";

          var req = "http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?"
          req += "command=find_video_by_id&token=" + encodeURIComponent(token);
          req += "&video_id=" + videoID;
          req += "&video_fields=id%2Cname%2CshortDescription%2CreferenceId&media_delivery=default//";
          req += "&callback=response";

          // Create a new request object
          bObj = new JSONscriptRequest(req);
          // Build the dynamic script tag
          bObj.buildScriptTag();
          // Add the script tag to the page
          bObj.addScriptTag();

        function response(jsonData) {
          jQuery('li.recent-episode-' + videoID ).find('h5').html(jsonData.name);
        }
```

I've tried using an each function as well without avail. I am sure I am just missing something in the Javascript, but you could use some help figuring it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of `videoID` in your function is global. You're updating its value each time you iterate through the script. By the time the callbacks are triggered (asynchronously) it's looped through and `videoID` has the last value you last set it to.

Since the JSON returned from the API includes the id, it would be simplest to just use that:

```
function response(jsonData) {
  jQuery('li.recent-episode-' + jsonData.id ).find('h5').html(jsonData.name);
}
```

Comment: Great idea. That worked great. Thanks for your help.